# Difference [brackets] and <shevrons> in a Javascript object

Tags: javascript

The methods [.getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) and [getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) both output a different kind of object. The method by classname outputs brackets `[div.child]` around it, and the id method shows the object using shevrons: `<div id="parent">`.

https://jsfiddle.net/Spindle/v1p9pqj0/1/

What is the difference between the two objects?

I'm looking for a way where I could test if the child node of a specific node is the same. However, I can't compare them because the object seems to be different somehow.

Comment: `testChild` is an array. Try `console.log(testChild[0]);`

Comment: Those have nothing to do with JavaScript (object) syntax. It's just the custom output formatting when logging lists (arrays, node lists, …) or DOM elements in your devtools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName()`  returns a collection of HTML elements while `getElementById()` returns a single element

Basically the `[]` denote a collection/array
And the `<>` denote an element